# Bathroom gfi won't work

Tags: bathroom

Here is a picture of the gfi I have power going to it but nothing works I have checked the breaker box the light is not on the gfi but it won't let me reset it have clue

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture would indeed be helpful, but it isn't there; if you can't edit it in, edit in the URL and someone will be along to edit it in. And, did this GFI ever work, and if so any idea what might have changed?

Comment: Yes -- did this GFCI ever work? Is it newly installed, or has it been there for a while? And if you can't edit in your picture and can't find a place to upload your picture, btw, try [imgur](https://imgur.com)

Comment: Typicallt GFCI's ship with warning tape on the LOAD terminals.  We would be keenly interested in anything you may have attached to either or both of those terminals.

Answer (score 1):

> it won't let me reset it

**If it used to work, and you have not changed the wiring:**

It's either defective, or there is a ground fault. They do seem to fail on a regular basis in the long view (I average 10-15 years, from what I recall of my GFCI failures.) But a fault of exactly the sort they are designed to prevent is always a possibility, until it's eliminated as a possibility.

**If it never worked or is newly installed:**

There's the additional possibility that it's wired incorrectly - incoming power goes to the "Line" terminals, any power going beyond connects to the "Load" terminals. When wired "backwards" they don't work.